# Find a matrix 4x4 that has no eigenvalues on $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

I had to find a matrix 2x2 and 4x4 that have no eigenvalues, for the 2x2 it was not that hard to do $a_{11}= 0$ $a_{12}= 1$ $a_{21}= -1$ $a_{22}= 0$ so that the possible eigenvalues are $det(xId-A)=x^2+1=x={-i,i}$, where A is the matrix with the $a_{ij}$ entries.

But I was not able to get to a 4x4 matrix

Comment: Just take $A=\begin{pmatrix} i & 0 & 0 \cr 0 & i & 0 \cr 0 & 0 & i \end{pmatrix}$. It has no real eigenvalues.

Comment: You mean to ask no real eigenvalue I guess...

Comment: Presumably the matrix must have real entries. Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a $3 \times 3$ real matrix, this does not exist.

Indeed, the characteristic polynomial of a $3 \times 3$ matrix is a polynomial of degree $3$, which has to vanish in $\mathbb{R}$. So there always exists an eigenvalue.

For a $4 \times 4$ matrix, consider the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0&-1\\
1 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0& 0& 1& 0
\end{pmatrix}

Its characteritic polynomial is $X^4 +1$.

Comment: I am so dumb, I double checked the question and it was on 4x4

Comment: The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial don't have to be real numbers. A general complex polynomial of degree 3 can in fact have no real roots.

Answer (score 1):

The $2\times 2$ case suggests that you look for a matrix with integer coefficients which does not have any real eigenvalue, like
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\Bbb Z).
$$
Try to generalize this for $n=4$ working with the group $SL_4(\Bbb Z)$. You can take block matrices with the matrix  from above, i.e.,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & -1& 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Its characteristic polynomial is $(X^2+1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Every** matrix **has** eigenvalues so you must mean "no *real* eigenvalues".  Non-real roots of a polynomial equation with *real* coefficients must come in complex conjugate pairs so there is NO 3 by 3 matrix, with *real* entries, that has 3 non-real eigenvalues.   Dietrich Burde gave an example of a 3 by 3 matrix with imaginary entries that has only imaginary entries.